# Character and skeleton moving when parenting and in edit mode

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, edit-mode

when trying to parent the model, and when going into edit mode, the armature moves up in the viewport drastically and the model does not parent. could this be an issue with something not being applied. The model did have a previous rig and animation of which the frames were deleted and the armature applied.
When moving the model with automatic weights even after deleting previous vertex groups the whole models when moving one bone with automatic weights.

[image]

Comment: So when you compare Pose Mode and Edit mode what do you observe?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/